# Redirection after click to another .html, pulling data from object

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I have an object (dataCenter.js) and it looks like this:

```
const productSrc = 'images/Products/'
const data = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Name of product 1',
            image: `${productSrc}/${1}.jpg`,
            description: 'Some description'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Name of product 2',
            image: `${productSrc}/${2}.jpg`,
            description: 'Some description'
        }, etc
```

On my index.html I have a swiper slider with picture of my products, names and buttons SEE MORE. I would like to when user click on SEE MORE to redirect on another page product.html which I created and it's empty, and there user should see bigger picture of product name under and full description.

My swiper slider:

```
<section class="product" id="products-container">

    <div class="heading">
        <h3>Kozmetički aparati</31>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper services-slider">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide slide">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="images/Aparati/1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h3>7U1 WATER OXYGEN HYDRAFACIAL</h3>
            <button class="myBtn btn card-btn"><a href='aparat.html?id=${item.id}'>Vidi više</a></button>
          </div>
        </div> etc
```

On my product.html I created a div with id product-info and I tried this code:

```
import data from './dataCenter.js';

const productInfo = document.getElementById('product-info');

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const id = urlParams.get('id');

const item = data[id];

const card = document.createElement('div');
card.classList.add("product-info-1");
const content = ` 
    <div class="product-image">
        <img src="${item.image}" class="product-thumb" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-2">
        <h2 class="product-brand">${item.name}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='description'>${item.description}</div> 
`;
card.innerHTML = content;

productInfo.appendChild(card);
```

After I reload on console I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
```

[image]

Comment: The `import` statement only usable with [**modules**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: please update on what exactly is not working: "don't know why but this doesn't work";  - I note you have no links to the second page if I read this properly

Comment: Your error means `item` is `undefined`, which means either `data` or `id` isn't what you think it is. See what logging those gives you, and chekc that `id` is a valid index within `data`.

Comment: Note that the code currently depends on a tenuous balance; that `id` is always going to match the index of the object in the `data` array. That's a recipe for disaster, in my opinion. I would change `const item = data[id];` to be `const item = data.find(el => el.id === id)` and check `item` for null, showing an error if it was not found.

Comment: Also, it is invalid in HTML to place an anchor element within a button. Either use a plain anchor (and use CSS to style it like a button if desired) or a button (although I'd advise against this as the anchor is used for elements that navigate when clicked).